# Can we apply the infinite sum formula if the common ratio is a complex number$?$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Suppose there is a series, an infinite series $$a+bi,(a+bi)^2,(a+bi)^3,\cdots$$

Can we apply the formula of $G.P$ to calculate its sum $\frac{a_1}{1-r}?$

Here the common ratio is a complex number. To my knowledge, the above formula can only be applied if $|r|<1$.

I was doing a problem in which we have to calculate limit $n$ tending to $\infty$ of a similar series. There, I mistakenly applied the above formula and got the same answer as given in the solution. But why is this so$?$ The complex number there was $$\frac{1+i\sqrt{5}}{6}$$

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure how you get $\sum x^k = 1$ for $x = 1$.

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio so are you saying that I have to look at the real part of the complex number and see if its absolute value is less than $1$ or not$??$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can.  The justification is basic algebra.

Letting $(z)$, rather than $(x)$ denote a complex variable, you have that

$$(1 + z + z^2 + \cdots + z^n)(1 - z) = 1 - z^{(n+1)}.$$

So, just as in Real Analysis, the issue is whether
the limit, as $n \to \infty$ of $z^n$ is $(0)$.  Putting this another way, just as in Real Analysis, when you estimate

$$(1 + z + z^2 + \cdots + z^n)$$

by

$$\frac{1}{1 - z},$$

the **error in the estimation** is

$$\frac{-z^{(n+1)}}{1-z}.$$

Since $z$ is presumably a fixed value, not equal to $[1 + i(0)]$, then the **error in the estimation** goes to $(0)$ if and only if

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} z^n = 0. \tag1 $$

The one wrinkle is that determining whether (1) above is true is a little tricky.  One way is that (1) is true if and only if

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} |z|^n = 0 \iff |z| < 1. \tag2 $$

The alternative approach is to express $z^n$ as $u(n) + iv(n)$, where $u$ and $v$ are real valued functions whose domain is the positive integers.

Then, you have that (1) above is true if and only if both of the following are true:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} u(n) = 0, ~~~ \lim_{n\to\infty} v(n) = 0.$$